# How to filter out useable data from csv files using python?

Tags: python, csv, parsing, machine-learning

Please help me in extracting important data from a .csv file using python. I got .csv file from 'citrine'.
I want to extract the element name and atomic percentage in the form of "Al2.5B0.02C0.025Co14.7Cr16.0Mo3.0Ni57.48Ti5.0W1.25Zr0.03"

***ORIGINAL***
***[{""element"":""Al"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""5.4""}},{""element"":""B"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""0.02""}},{""element"":""C"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""0.13""}},{""element"":""Co"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""7.5""}},{""element"":""Cr"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""6.1""}},{""element"":""Mo"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""2.0""}},{""element"":""Nb"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""0.5""}},{""element"":""Ni"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""61.0""}},{""element"":""Re"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""0.5""}},{""element"":""Ta"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""9.0""}},{""element"":""Ti"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""1.0""}},{""element"":""W"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""5.8""}},{""element"":""Zr"",""idealAtomicPercent"":{""value"":""0.13""}}]***

[Original CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0zTm.png)
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhi2r.png)

Comment: You won't get much help if you insist on posting your input and output data as images. We prefer something we can copy--paste. Learn to use [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Without having the file structure it is hard to tell.

Try to load the file using:

```
import csv

with open(file_path) as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(...)
```

You will have to figure out the arguments for the function which depend on the file.